# Automating clicks using curl

Tags: bash, curl, automation

As a foreword I'd like to mention that I know little to nothing about programming. Everything I'm doing I've looked up online, so I'm sorry if I'm making questions that might seem vacuous to you. Thanks in advance.

---

I’m working on webpage #1, e.g http://website.com/page.php?action=showall, which displays links of the form http://website.com/someotherpage.php?ID=12345, on which I have to click, among other links. I was entering this on the mac terminal

```
curl 'http://website.com/login.php' -XPOST --data 'email=EMAIL&pass=PASS&submit=+'  --cookie-jar ./login
curl --cookie ./login http://website.com/someotherpage.php?ID=[1-12345]
```

But webpage #1 doesn't necessarily include all IDs in the range from 1 to 12345; some IDs in this range don't actually exist. I was wondering if it was possible to just open the urls contained in webpage one, of the form given above. On the page source they're listed as

```
<a href='someotherpage.php?ID=223670'>Open</a>
```

Also, webpage #1 only displays 50 links at a time, so when I'm done clicking I have to refresh and click on the next 50. How could I loop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible, yes, but curl can't do it alone, and bash is not a ***suitable*** scripting language for parsing HTML. however, this would easy with a better scripting language, like PHP, Python, Perl, or pretty much anything with support for libxml+libcurl. for example, install php-cli, and try this php script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$email = '???';
$password = '???';
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => "", // enables cookie handling in ram, without needing a file.
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://website.com/login.php',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( array (
                'email' => $email,
                'pass' => $pass,
                'submit' => '' 
        ) ),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1 
) );
$html = curl_exec ( $ch );
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html );
$xp = new DOMXPath ( $domd );
foreach ( $xp->query ( '//a[text()="Open"]' ) as $openUrl ) {
    $url = "http://website.com/" . $openUrl->getAttribute ( "href" );
    echo "visiting $url     ..";
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_exec ( $ch );
    echo " done.\n";
}
```

this will parse out and visit any `<a>` links with the exact text "Open", which is fetched with the [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) `//a[text()="Open"]`

where

1. `//` means `start from the very top of the document`
2. `a` means `find <a> tags`
3. `[...]` means `with conditions`
4. `text()` means "get the text content of the element being scanned"
5. `="Open"` - check if it has exact content "Open"

Comment: Firstly, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I have a small problem though... I tried brewing php-cli, but it didn't find it. From where can I compile it? Or does php suffice? I have php installed, but when I enter the script the process just keeps on running

Comment: @AlexD what operating system are you on? (Mac? Linux? Windows? *BSD? ~)

Comment: macos high sierra

Comment: @AlexD well... it sounds weird, but according to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.bundled.php), php seems to be bundled by default. what do you get if you write `php -v`  in a terminal?

Comment: @AlexD according to people on the freenode Mac channel, High Sierra comes bundled with php-cli by default (PHP 7.1.16 cli), which means you just need to paste my code to a file called script.php , then open a terminal and write `php script.php`, and it should run. alternatively, write `chmod +x script.php` , then `./script.php` , and it should run.